# Textures not appearing

Tags: c#, directx, textures

[image]Posted this earlier and one person replied with any suggestion, so I'll post one more time I think. I realise it's old technology we're alkling about here, but still - I'm stuck. So any thoughts - anything - would be appreciated.

I'm currently working my way through "Beginning C# Programming", and have hit a problem in chapter 7 when drawing textures.

I have used the same code as on the demo CD, and although I had to change the path of the texture to be absolute, when rendered it is appearing grey.

I have debugged the program to write to file the loaded texture, and this is fine - no problems there. So something after that point is going wrong.

Here are some snippets of code:

```
public void InitializeGraphics()
{
    // set up the parameters
    Direct3D.PresentParameters p = new Direct3D.PresentParameters();
    p.SwapEffect = Direct3D.SwapEffect.Discard;
    ...
    graphics = new Direct3D.Device( 0, Direct3D.DeviceType.Hardware, this,
    Direct3D.CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, p );
    ...
    // set up various drawing options
    graphics.RenderState.CullMode = Direct3D.Cull.None;
    graphics.RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable = true;
    graphics.RenderState.AlphaBlendOperation = Direct3D.BlendOperation.Add;
    graphics.RenderState.DestinationBlend = Direct3D.Blend.InvSourceAlpha;
    graphics.RenderState.SourceBlend = Direct3D.Blend.SourceAlpha;
    ...
}

public void InitializeGeometry()
{
    ...
    texture = Direct3D.TextureLoader.FromFile( 
            graphics, "E:\\Programming\\SharpDevelop_Projects\\AdvancedFrameworkv2\\texture.jpg", 0, 0, 0, 0, Direct3D.Format.Unknown,
            Direct3D.Pool.Managed, Direct3D.Filter.Linear, 
            Direct3D.Filter.Linear, 0 );
...
}

protected virtual void Render()
{
    graphics.Clear( Direct3D.ClearFlags.Target, Color.White , 1.0f, 0 );
    graphics.BeginScene();

    // set the texture
    graphics.SetTexture( 0, texture );

    // set the vertex format
    graphics.VertexFormat = Direct3D.CustomVertex.TransformedTextured.Format;

    // draw the triangles
    graphics.DrawUserPrimitives( Direct3D.PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, 2, vertexes );

    graphics.EndScene();
    graphics.Present();
    ...
}
```

I can't figure out what is going wrong here. Obviously if I load up the texture in windows it displays fine - so there's something not right in the code examples given in the book. It doesn't actually work, and there must be something wrong with my environment presumably.

Comment: Can you please add how you define your vertices?

Comment: Hey Nico just spring cleaning on here. I got all this sorted in the end. Cheers.